# AsyncTask and Udp packets

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm getting "NetworkOnMainThreadException"

I'm sending UDP packets from a AsyncTask **but** from a Sensor event, my guess is that the Sensor event triggers on the main UI thread.

I want to send UdpPackets when new values are available from the sensor, what is the best way since I cant do it from the sensor event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spawning a thread for each sensor event isn't very good, and have a separate thread that polls new data also has problems (WarrenFaith answer).

I ended up using a CyclicBarrier, like this, a infinite loop inside a seperate thread

```
running = true;
worker = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run(){

         while(running) {
             try {
                 sync.await();
                 Send();
             } catch(Exception e) {}
         }
         socket.disconnect();
    }
}); 
worker.start();
```

The thread will halt on the `sync.await();` line

Until new data is available from the sensor

```
SensorEventListener allListener = new SensorEventListener() {
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if(sendOrientation) {
            float R[] = new float[9];
            float I[] = new float[9];
            boolean success = sensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, acc, mag);
            if (success) {  
                SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);    
            }
        }

        if(sync.getNumberWaiting() > 0)
            sync.reset();   
    }
    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {    
    }
};
```

And `sync.reset();` is called, which will let the poller thread proceed

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @RaghavSood is indeed solid (voted up) but I think you should try to avoid workarounds. So basically the following is the extension of 2. of Raghavs answer.

My solution would include a Queue or Stack where you collect your Sensor data and every x seconds (a not to narrow interval) you should start your AsyncTask and send the data to your server. This has one advantage:

- You prevent spamming data including connect and disconnect to you server. This should reduce power consumption on your phone and prevent the server from being flooded by data.

and one disadvantage:

- Your data will be collected before sending which means your data sending will not be instantaneously.

Comment: The sensor event listener hook up sets the frequency of updates, so I would like to fire Udpo packets at this rate, if have  seperate thread i will have to SLeep that thread between each new data not to starve that CPU core. I'm a .net developer mainly and there you can sync threads using something called AutoResetEvent from the sensor thread you could then do resetEvent.Set() and from the udp thread do resetEvent.Wait() and it will wait there until the Set method is executed. This way i can keep the sensor events frequence without intruding alot of extra code

Comment: Then use Threads instead of AsyncTask and just fire away. But keep in mind that the server needs to be able to handle the data, too. Meaning if you publish this app and have x thousand user, you might get some heavy server load...

Comment: Well I dont want to fire away, I want to fire when the sensor event has fired, since i cant to it from teh sensor event I need some way of sycjing the two threads, CyclicBarrier might do it, just looking into it

Comment: Thats what I meant. If you create a normal `Thread` you can fire your udp packages from everywhere as you aren't on the UI Thread anymore.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but its not exactly an answer to my problem, so wont accept it as answer, I added my own solution below

Comment: Your solution is what I mean by "Then use Threads instead of AsyncTask and just fire away". Glad you found your working solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. Change your target SDK to anything below Honeycomb, or diable StrictMode
2. Spawn a new thread or AsyncTask to send the data to the server.

Changing the target SDK:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="<your-minimum>" android:targetSdkVersion="9" /> //9 is GB
```

Diable StrictMode:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: I wasnt the one, but this sounds like a ugly workaround, so I understand why they did it. But they didntr see 2) i guess

Comment: The cleanest way is to do it in a back ground thread. The other two are workarounds, but they do work, though I wouldn't recommend them in a production app.

Comment: Spawningng a new thread for Each sensor event will not work due to performance issues, do java have something similar to AutoResetEvents in C#, that way I could have a seperate thrtead that syncs using reset events

Comment: I'm not familiar with C#, sorry. Could you post the problematic code? I do have some experience with Android, so maybe I can provide a cleaner solution.

Comment: CyclicBarrier is might what im after will get back with results :D

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but its not exactly an answer to my problem, so wont accept it as answer, I added my own solution below